# Text-Truncate class is not working at various browser size If browser size is small

Tags: html, css

I am writing a chat room message template. I used a text-truncate class for long message ellipse. But It is not working in my code.

```
<div style="display: flex; background-color: beige; font-size: 14px; width: 10%;">
    <!-- favorite-->
    <div>
        <img src="./images/ic-mentor.png" style="border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; width: 75px; height: 75px;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <img src="./images/ic-mentor.png"/>
            <span>
                TEST_USER
            </span>
            <span>
                <!-- &nbsp;|&nbsp; -->
                <!-- Characters -->
                
            </span>
            <span style="float:right">
                PM 01:16
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-truncate">
            adssasdaasdsadsaasdadsadssdasdadsaadsadssadasasddassad
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above code is my sample code. I want to write a working at small browser size with truncate class. But my code is not working text truncate.

I don't want to set width. I want to make flexible template, If I set width, then it does not use in small size browser

[image]
I don't want to overflow contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of the div that's containing the overflowing content. Else truncate class will not produce ellipses.

Try this code:

```
<div style="display: flex; background-color: beige; font-size: 14px; width: 10%;">
    <!-- favorite-->
    <div>
        <img src="./images/ic-mentor.png" style="border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; width: 75px; height: 75px;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <img src="./images/ic-mentor.png"/>
            <span>
                TEST_USER
            </span>
            <span>
                <!-- &nbsp;|&nbsp; -->
                <!-- Characters -->
                
            </span>
            <span style="float:right">
                PM 01:16
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-truncate" style="width: 300px;">
            adssasdaasdsadsaasdadsadssdasdadsaadsadssadasasddassad
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I've added inline-styles for now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to set width. I want to make flexible template, If I set width, then it does not use in small size browser.

Comment: Without the width set, the text-truncate does not get applied. You'll have to use a media query to remove the width on smaller devices. Note: You'll have to remove the inline styles for this.

Comment: I want to set width : 100% , but it is does not work. why not?

Comment: Likewise if I set width to 30%, then contents overflow. I only want to use parent area(first div tag - widdth : 10%)

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this problem myself as follows:

```
<div style="display: flex; background-color: beige; font-size: 14px; width: 10%;">
    <!-- favorite-->
    <div>
        <img src="./images/ic-mentor.png" style="border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; width: 75px; height: 75px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-truncate" style="flex-grow: 1;">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <img src="./images/ic-mentor.png"/>
            <span>
                TEST_USER
            </span>
            <span>
                <!-- &nbsp;|&nbsp; -->
                <!-- Characters -->
                
            </span>
            <span style="float:right">
                PM 01:16
            </span>
        </div>
     adssasdaasdsadsaasdadsadssdasdadsaadsadssadasasddassad
    </div>
</div>
```

I just remove the text-truncate div tag and then put parent div tag.